# How to slice starting from negative to a positive index or the opposite

Tags: python, numpy

Numpy cannot perform the following indexing:

```
a = np.arange(10)
a[-2: 2]
```

I'm doing it in a not very elegant way at the moment, is there a trick or oneliner to get that?

Notice that I don't know if I'm facing this scenario in my code, it does happen sometimes, so I'm looking for a dynamic and one-for-all solution, not something for this exact case only.

My generalized slicer, quite long.

```
def slicer(array, lower_, upper_):
    n = len(array)
    lower_ = lower_ % n  # if negative, you get the positive equivalent. If > n, you get principal value.
    roll = lower_
    lower_ = lower_ - roll
    upper_ = upper_ - roll
    array_ = np.roll(array, -roll)
    upper_ = upper_ % n
    return array_[lower_: upper_]
```

Comment: Can't you simply say: a[-2:] + a[:2]

Comment: @PeterPesch Firstly, you're assuming Python lists not numpy arrays, + adds doesn't concatenate. Secondly, yes, ofcourse, but I don't know where/when this is going to happen in my program so that I do this trick.

Comment: `b=a.tolist()` and `np.array(b[-2:]+b[:2])` is a 2-line solution

Comment: @rpoleski Thanks, but I don't know if that is the case indeed. i.e. I don't know if I'm facing such a scenario in the first place, so I want it tp be dynamic and work for all cases. I will update the question to make it clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [71]: slicer(np.arange(10),-2,2)                                                                    
Out[71]: array([8, 9, 0, 1])
```

It looks like `np.r_` does the kind of 'roll' that you want:

```
In [72]: np.arange(10)[np.r_[-2:2]]                                                                    
Out[72]: array([8, 9, 0, 1])
In [73]: np.r_[-2:2]                                                                                   
Out[73]: array([-2, -1,  0,  1])
```

There may be differences between what you expect, and what `r_` does.  I'll let you study its docs.

Just because you call it slicing, it isn't `basic` indexing.  However done, the result is a `copy`, not a `view`.  And beware of any kind of extension to multidimensional indexing.

Be careful about seeking an all-case replacement.  The use of negative index to mark from-the-end, without wrapping, is so deeply embedded in Python and numpy, that you should always assume that's the default behavior.

```
In [77]: np.arange(10)[-2:2]                                                                           
Out[77]: array([], dtype=int64)
```

Treat your wrapped/roll case as an exception, one the requires special handling.

Comment: Thanks. I was waiting for your answer. I am aware of all those subtilties you mentioned. `np.r_` seems to fix half of the problem like when **jumping** from negative to positive indices while slicing. But it certainly doesn't work for `a[8:2]` where `a` has a size of 10. In this case there's  **jumping** from other end of the array to its begining. Okay, so you suggest I should handle it manually as an exception. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def slicer(a, lower, upper):
    if lower < 0:
        return np.concatenate((a[lower:], a[:upper]))
    else:
        return a[lower: upper]
```

I think it's relatively simple.

Comment: It does. In that case it's equivalent to `np.arange(10)[8: -2]` and returns `[]`.

Comment: Making it work for `a[8: 2]` is something different than what you asked in the question. `np.arange(10)[8: 2]` returns empty array (same in my code) and you haven't indicated that your expected result is different.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you know the length, you can just add the length of your array to lower and upper if they are < 0. You can then check if upper is smaller than lower, and concatenate if necessary.

```
def slicer(a, lower, upper):
    if lower < 0:
        lower += len(a)
    if upper < 0:
        upper += len(a)
    if upper < lower:
        return np.concatenate([a[lower:], a[:upper]])
    return a[lower:upper]
```

Comment: One thing that is a bit odd about this is when lower and upper are both negative, but lower > upper. In that case you wrap around the entire array, which is expected, but still kind of weird.